# Salesforce Data Migration Jitterbit Response Error

Tags: jitterbit

I have used Jitterbit Harmony to migrate datas. It works if I run operations by one by. But If I linked two operation on "on Success"(It means first operation is success, pass and run the second one), it doesn't work and give that error "No response from server". But The first operation is working successfully. Is there any point to solve this error?